# multithreading using pool.map takes longer time than normal single process

Tags: python, multithreading, threadpool

I want to parallelize a task using python, so I read about pool.map, where data is divided into multiple chunks and processed by each process (thread).
I have a huge dictionary(2 million words) and a text file of sentences, the idea is to divide sentences into words and match each word to the exiting dictionary and do further processing based on the return result. Before doing that ,I wrote a dummy program to check the functionality of pool.map but it is not working as expected (i.e single process takes less time than multiple process) (I am using process and thread interchangeably because I think every thread is nothing but a process here)

```
def add_1(x):
    return (x*x+x)

def main():
    iter = 10000000
    num = [i for i in xrange(iter)]
    threads = 4
    pool = ThreadPool(threads)  
    start = time.time()
    results = pool.map(add_1,num,iter/threads)
    pool.close()
    pool.join()
    end = time.time()
    print('Total Time Taken = %f')% (end-start)
```

Total Time Taken:

```
Thread 1    Total Time Taken = 2.252361
Thread 2    Total Time Taken = 2.560798
Thread 3    Total Time Taken = 2.938640
Thread 4    Total Time Taken = 3.048179

Just using  pool = ThreadPool()
def main:

   num = [i for i in xrange(iter)]
   #pool = ThreadPool(threads)
   pool = ThreadPool()
   start = time.time()
   #results = pool.map(add_1,num,iter/threads)
   results = pool.map(add_1,num)
   pool.close()
   pool.join()
   end = time.time()
   print('Total Time Taken = %f')% (end-start)
```

Total Time Taken = 3.031125

Normal for loop execution:

```
def main():

    iter = 10000000
    start = time.time()
    for k in xrange(iter):
        add_1(k)
    end = time.time()
    print ('Total Time normally = %f') % (end-start)
```

Total Time normally = 1.087591

Config:
I am using python  2.7.6

Comment: It takes longer with multi-threading because of the overhead involved. It has to split the process up and them recombine it at the end

Comment: Even if I increase the size of the list it takes a long time. I can understand for a small size input combining all the outputs of individual threads is an overhead. But for large size it should work, i want to know the reason why its not working even for large size input?